# How to pass argument from one view to another view?

Tags: 7, views

I have filter  in separate view and want to pass the value to another view and get the filter result in Drupal.

**Scenario:** I have two views, one for filter and another for filter result.

I want to filter based the `content: title`. In another view I have to fetch the result and display based on title filter.

My question: How can I argument from one view to another view?

Comment: Try this *Views_field_view* module

Comment: @logeshvaran before you comment I answer it with suggest use this module ;)

Comment: @zhilevan okay fine

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do it programmatically:

```
// load and display view A
$view_A = views_get_view('view_A_name');
// execute view
$view_A->execute();
// get all nids from the result 
foreach ($view_A->result as $result) {
   // capture the result of your field in an array. 
   $values[] = $result->field_machine_name; 
}
// render view
print $view_A->render();

// now load view B
$view_B = views_get_view('view_B_name');
// set arguments for view
$view_B->set_arguments(array(implode(",", $values)));
// execute view
$view_B->execute();
// render view
print $view_B->render();
```

Comment: Vote up, programmatically method is another method for achieve this,

Comment: where to write the code I have two view tpl parent(perspective.tpl) and child (submenu.tpl) In which file I have to write this code

Comment: @user3386779 pick one and write all the code there.

Answer (score 2):

Use  [Views Field View module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view)

> There are a lot of cases in views where you want to embed a list
>   inside each row. One example could be, you have a list of groups, and
>   for each groups you want to list the first and last name of all of
>   their members.
>
> This can be achieved with this module, as views_field_view allows you
>   to embed one view into another view and pass arguments along.

And Also if You are developer and you want to achieve it programmatically you can use [views_get_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view/7.x-3.x) function.

Comment: how to use this module.I have two tpl file

Comment: install that module, the in your primary views, in golobal section add View field and pass title to secondary views, see some tutorial about how use this module ( it's very simple ) as example https://www.webomelette.com/view-within-view-fields-module

Comment: @user3386779 did you try that?