# Exclude results in view that appear in attachment

Tags: views, 8

I'm using a view with an attachment to create a block that shows a featured news item with a large picture at the top and the rest of the news with just thumbnails beneath it. The featured news item is in an attachment, and the thumbnails are part of normal block view. The featured news item is whatever news item has 'featured' selected and is the most recent. However as it is now the base view block will redundantly display the news item again even if it's featured above.

I understand that in the base block view I could just do 'if not featured' but many items can have the featured field checked when only the most recent is displayed.

I've looked at creating custom view filters but I was having trouble understanding how to make them and I worried that I was moving in the wrong direction.

Is there a way to exclude a result in a view that appears in an attachment?

Comment: You can achieve this by programmatically printing the views, and capturing in an array the nids of the first view and passing them as an argument to the other view. Basically, you'll need to do the D8 version of [my answer here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228409/how-to-pass-argument-from-one-view-to-another-view/228418#228418)